# Python: Distribute numbers in a given array equally

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array like:

```
a=np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,1360,1360,130,77,77,77,0,0,0,0,230,230,230])
```

Now i want to euqally distribute those numbers between 0 and 255 or 0 and 65.535. And that the same numbers in the start array are same number in the end array. The purpose behind this is to clearly see different colors in a picture, which will be created from the array. 0 should always stay 0.What the start numbers are and what they become in the end is not important. It is only important that the distance between one number and its previous and next number is the same.And it is important that the numbers are integers

**example end array**

```
b=np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,51,51,51,102,102,153,204,204,0,0,0,0,255,255,255])
```

Comment: Could you explain how did you come from `a` to `b`? It is not clear why, for example, `1360` became `102`, and `230` became `255`.

Comment: It is not important which numbers they had before. It is only important that the distance between is the same

Comment: *"The distance between"* is **not** the same: the distance between 2 and 1360 is not the same as the distance between 51 and 102; not even the ratio. If you provide a well defined rule someone could help you

Comment: So you're trying to categorise each distinct numerical value? Then for each category you want to assign a distinct (visually and numerically) grayscale hue to each category? What about 0 and 1, they extremely hard to differentiate.

Comment: @Gsk You are right, i ment that the distance between the prevoipus and next number in the array is the same. So in case b it is "51"

Comment: @Dunes Yeah would be nice, but the numbers in the end are labels, so they have to be other numbers than 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution. It just collects the number of distinct categories (in the order they first appear). Then calculates a mapping of the final hue / label for each category. Before finally creating `b` from the mapping.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,1360,1360,130,77,77,77,0,0,0,0,230,230,230]

categories = OrderedDict.fromkeys(l)
categories.pop(0, None)

max_label = 255

for i, category in enumerate(categories, start=1):
    label = max_label * i / len(categories)
    categories[category] = int(round(label))

categories[0] = 0

b = [categories[v] for v in l]

assert b == [
    42, 42, 42, 0, 0, 0, 85, 85, 85, 128, 128, 170, 212, 212, 212,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255
]
```

Comment: It works well! My problem is that the array has a dtype of unint32 in the beginning and it is really large (6GB). When the relabeling is done I want to save it as 8bit or 16bit depending how many different unique numbers are in the array. The OrdererdDict causes a memory error. So is there a way to reduce the memory consuption?

Comment: Do your labels need to be monotonically increasing? In that case you might be able to use numpy functions. But it also depends on how much memory you have available. Are you sure you will always have less than 65k distinct values?

Comment: Yes they will be alwys under 65k. What do you mean with monotonically increasing?

Comment: In your example, your label values always increase. Could an acceptable output for `[1, 0, 2, 3]`, be `[255, 0, 1, 127]`? That is, where the label values both increase and decrease throughout the array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can achieve the desired result by sorting the `set` of your list, find the integer of the highest gap possible in given range (i.e. 255), and assign at each number in your list the value corresponding at the index's number multiplied by the gap:

```
start_list = [1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,1360,1360,130,77,77,77,0,0,0,0,230,230,230]


mapping = sorted(set(start_list)) # [0, 1, 2, 77, 130, 230, 1360]

gap = 255//len(set(start_list)) # 36

end_list = [gap*mapping.index(x) for x in start_list]

print(end_list) # [36, 36, 36, 0, 0, 0, 72, 72, 72, 216, 216, 144, 108, 108, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 180, 180]
```